# Is the Alfresco repository document version history available via CIFS/FTP?

Tags: alfresco

I am using Alfresco 4.0.e. I want to know if it is somehow possible to see the document version history (older versions of documents) via the CIFS/FTP interface of Alfresco?

The problem I am really approaching is to hide the version history of documents to users without specific properties. I want to know if this problem can be reduced to applying my changes in alfresco share? Note that I have assumed alfresco explorer (the previous version of alfrescos web client) won't be available for users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but it should not be too difficult implementing something basic.

The CIFS and FTP protocol have no clue what a version history is. If you want to see it through them you will have to implement a custom solution reflecting the version history based on files and/or folders. A simple approach would be an accompanying file per versioned file showing the information you need. The content could be updated automatically using a behaviour.

Another option would be to implement a custom desktop action showing it, but that would most likely use http based communication.

Comment: Thanks, Actually I am happier that CIFS/FTP doesn't understand version history, as I said in my problem statement!