# Alfresco : Increase document version when overriding file in ftp

Tags: ftp, alfresco

I want to increase minor document version when overriding file in ftp. When I traced the code, `ContentDiskDriver2.truncateFile()` works for overriding file. Inside this function I use `versionService` to increase version. Following code is written in truncateFile()
try {

```
    NodeRef nodeRef = getNodeForPath(tree, DriverContent.FILE_OPEN_PARAMS.getPath());
    System.out.println("Node Ref: " + nodeRef);

    // Increase minor version to file.
    Map<String, Serializable> versionProperties = new HashMap<String, Serializable>(2, 1.0f);
    versionProperties.put(Version.PROP_DESCRIPTION, "");
    versionProperties.put(VersionModel.PROP_VERSION_TYPE, VersionType.MINOR);

    VersionService versionService = (VersionService) applicationContext.getBean("versionService");
    versionService.createVersion(nodeRef, versionProperties);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But unfortunately I got this error.

```
2013-01-02 14:12:31,609  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [Sess_FTP3_192.168.1.166] Error from JLAN
 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 00020073 Transaction must be active and synchronization is required: Thread[Sess_FTP3_192.168.1.166,5,FTPSessions]
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.AlfrescoTransactionSupport.registerSynchronizations(AlfrescoTransactionSupport.java:467)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.AlfrescoTransactionSupport.getSynchronization(AlfrescoTransactionSupport.java:451)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.AlfrescoTransactionSupport.getResource(AlfrescoTransactionSupport.java:244)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.TransactionalResourceHelper.incrementCount(TransactionalResourceHelper.java:71)
    at org.alfresco.repo.policy.BehaviourFilterImpl.disableBehaviour(BehaviourFilterImpl.java:158)
    at org.alfresco.repo.version.Version2ServiceImpl.createVersion(Version2ServiceImpl.java:212)
    at org.alfresco.repo.version.Version2ServiceImpl.createVersion(Version2ServiceImpl.java:140)
    at org.alfresco.filesys.repo.ContentDiskDriver2.increaseVersion(ContentDiskDriver2.java:2937)
    at org.alfresco.filesys.repo.ContentDiskDriver2.truncateFile(ContentDiskDriver2.java:1652)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
    at $Proxy97.truncateFile(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.filesys.repo.NonTransactionalRuleContentDiskDriver.truncateFile(NonTransactionalRuleContentDiskDriver.java:480)
    at org.alfresco.filesys.repo.LegacyFileStateDriver.truncateFile(LegacyFileStateDriver.java:471)
    at org.alfresco.filesys.repo.BufferedContentDiskDriver.truncateFile(BufferedContentDiskDriver.java:532)
    at org.alfresco.jlan.ftp.FTPSrvSession.procStoreFile(FTPSrvSession.java:2262)
    at org.alfresco.jlan.ftp.FTPSrvSession.run(FTPSrvSession.java:4924)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Can you help me how to solve **Transaction must be active and synchronization is required**

I found this link..
[Is the Alfresco repository document version history available via CIFS/FTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083086/is-the-alfresco-repository-document-version-history-available-via-cifs-ftp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've been caught by "little letter" vs "Big Letter" Alfresco services

"little letter" services are the raw services, and normally only used within other Alfresco low level services. "Big Letter" services are the wrapped user facing services, which include transactions, auditing, security etc.

For your case, you need to use the Big Letter form, so change the line

```
VersionService versionService = (VersionService) applicationContext.getBean("versionService");
```

To the correct one:

```
VersionService versionService = (VersionService) applicationContext.getBean("VersionService");
```

And you'll get a copy of the VersionService with transactions, security etc, which is what I think you need for your situation. (Note that the bean is fetched with a Big First Letter rather than little letter)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation...Now I can solve according to your explanation.... I found another alternative solution. Can you favor me to check it?

Answer (score 0):

This is alternative solution I found. The use of transaction explicitly.

```
    VersionService versionService = (VersionService) applicationContext.getBean("VersionService");
    TransactionService transactionService = (TransactionService) applicationContext.getBean("transactionService");

    UserTransaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = transactionService.getUserTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        versionService.createVersion(nodeRef, versionProperties);
        tx.commit();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        if(tx != null)
        {
            try
            {
                tx.rollback();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) 
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e2) 
            {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SystemException e3) 
            {
                e3.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would advise against doing this. If you really do want to use the little letter service directly (and hence worry about security, auditing etc), you'll want to use a RetryingTransaction instead. Otherwise, you'll have intermittent failures when retryable problems (mostly transaction conflicts) occur